# App memory usage and memory allocation is different

Tags: android

I am working on app. When I check the used memory of app in device it shows the 50 MB (By Going in setting and app and running process . But at same time when I check the app allocated and free memory it is just MB.
How can I get the exact figure.

Comment: are you doing `Bitmap` related in your process ?

Comment: are you compilng hard Bitmaps or Requesting HTTPs?

Comment: and some memory not managed by vm(dalvik/art).

Comment: Yes , I am working on Bitmap

Comment: Solve by recycling the bitmaps and removing the instance of bitmap when it is not in used